# Asp.Net MVC authorization not authenticating in Web API call

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, asp.net-identity, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.Net MVC app based on the default Visual Studio template, using individual user accounts over asp.net identity.
After logging in, the calls to the MVC Controllers show the user as being authenticated, and I can cast to SecurityIdentity to check for claims.

However, when I make a call to a Web API controller in the same project, the Request shows up as NOT authenticated.  How can I use the authentication information from my mvc logon and pass that to the Web API controllers, so that those requests also show up as Authenticated on the server.

EDIT 1 Dec 2015:

I should probably mention I'm using angular.js (and KendoUI) to make calls to the api controllers on the server. These posts have no authentication info, and thus the Request.IsAuthenticated on the server side returns false. How do I get identity information into these ajax posts to the api?

I thought the cookie that gets returned to the browser after successful MVC logon gets automatically appended by the browser to all subsequent posts to the same server? It does so for calls to my mvc controllers (where Request.IsAuthenticated == true), but not for ajax posts to my api controllers

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the Authorize[Roles="Role1, Role2"] attribute on the API actions just like with non API controllers.

If you need to access the claims however, the UserManager is accessed with:

HttpContext.**Current**.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager()

and a reference to Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin is required.

Comment: Hi Marius,  this does not answer my question.  The core problem I have is that the request to the API methods shows up as unauthenticated.

Comment: If you user is authenticated in one but not the other, it means there is something wrong with the configuration of your Identity Manager. Can you at least access your user?

Comment: Well the issue is that the ajax post to any api route does not contain any authentication information.  So on the server side, the Request.IsAuthenticated returns false.